# List with managed metadata and TaxCatchAll always returns the default language of the term

Tags: list, managed-metadata, taxonomy, hidden

I changed my language and it looks fine in the sharepoint list itself. The language was changed. If i make this request i will always get the default language from the hidden list.

```
/_api/lists/GetByTitle('Listname')/items?$select=*,TaxCatchAll/ID,TaxCatchAll/Term&$expand=TaxCatchAll
```

Is there any way to get the current translation from the list? It's not possible to translate a sharepoint list with this taxonomy problem.

Thank you for any help.